# Call laravel route inside javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

Is there a way to call a Laravel route (with ID) inside a javascript?

Right now I'm getting encoded results and I'm stuck with this. I appreciate any help!. TY
I have this redirect link inside a javascript. This href is inside a datatable, once I click an icon it will redirect me to the page.

```
 return `<a href = "{{ route('smshistory.view', ['id' => $smshistory->id]) }}" class="btn btn-link btn-success btn-just-icon btn-round" title="SMS History">
     <i class="material-icons">sms</i>
     <div class="ripple-container"></div>
 </a>`;
```

**My route**:

```
Route::get('sms-history/{id}', 'SmsHistoryController@getView')->name('smshistory');
```

**My controller**:

```
public function getView($id) {
    $smshistory = SmsOutboundsHistory::find($id);
    return view('sms-history', compact('smshistory'));
}
```

I'm getting an encoded results for this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7B%20route('smshistory.view',%20['id'%20=%3E%20$smshistory-%3Eid])%20%7D%7D
```

I would like to have it like this. The URL + id

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/sms-history/2
```

Comment: Make your your view file end with **blade.php** as `view.blade.php`

Comment: from where you are using this js code?? in a blade file or in a js file??

Comment: I have the href code inside a JS file

Comment: `{{ }}` is a blade directive so will only work in .blade.php files. You could put something like `<script>window.smshistoryUrl = "{{ route('smshistory.view', ['id' => $smshistory->id]) }}"; </script>` and then use it in your .js file as `window.smshistoryUrl`

Comment: Ok, I tried that but whenever I added that code <script>window.smshistoryUrl = "{{ route('smshistory.view', ['id' => $smshistory->id]) }}"; </script>

on my blade file, it gives me an error:
ErrorException {#1551 ▼
  #message: "Undefined variable: smshistory"

I added the "href = '+window.smshistoryUrl+'" on my JS file

Comment: Are you adding the above script to the view `smshistory.view` ?

Comment: no, there is no smshistory.view, I edited my question, the href is actually from a different blade inside a datatable. Once I click on the icon from the datatable it will redirect me to the sms-history page + the ID in the url

Comment: Try using Laravel's {!! !!} notation in your blade file for this. Javascript will recognize it and it will escape your string. For example: `{!! route('something', ['id' => 1]) !!}`

Comment: I was able to get around this issue. Thanks for all the inputs. I do have another question and I'm creating a new question post for it.